# Android ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() Permission Denied

Tags: android, permissions, image-capture

I'm using the latest Android Activity Result API for taking pictures with the device camera:

```
    private val takePictureActivityResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSuccess ->
            if (isSuccess) {
                if (imageUri != Uri.EMPTY) {
                    // SAVE image to external storage
                    currentImagePath = ImageUtils.saveImageToExternalStorage(this,imageUri)
                    addImageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
                }
            }
        }
```

This results in a SecurityException:

`java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.activity.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{81d69c 11563:com.myapp/u0a242} (pid=11563, uid=10242) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA`

According to Google's documentation:

`If your app targets M and above and declares as using the Manifest.permission.CAMERA permission which is not granted, then attempting to use this action will result in a SecurityException.`

I'm not using `android.permission.CAMERA` in the manifest, nor does the app explicitly request camera permissions from the user. I don't understand how a permission could have been revoked if the app never requested it. I do save images to device storage, so those permissions are in the manifest.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can explain this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Double check you do not have the CAMERA permission in you APK.

1. Go to your `app` module's AndroidManifest.xml file.
2. Click the `Merged Manifest` button below the code area.